# RequestMapping redirecting Error404

Tags: spring, jsp

please help me with Spring's RequestMapping. I want my web app prints cities when I click country(url). So I created WebController, which has this RequestMapping.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/cities/{cityId}", method = RequestMethod.GET )
        public List <City> searchCityById( @PathVariable ("cityId") Long cityId) {


            return ciserv.searchCityById(cityId);
        }
```

ciserv - my Service, it work fine
and countrylist.jsp, which has

```
<c:forEach items="${countryList}" var="country">

        <br />
        <td><a href="cities/${country.id}">${country.name}</a></td>
    </c:forEach>
```

so it print me countries(with url) when Im clicking country url, it redirect me to rightly localhost/myproject/cities/(id of country), but it show me error 404 - resource is not available.  How I can solve it? And this function of my webapp I need to do with RequestMapping or I need to use anotherway? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like you're using a relative path for the country links/URLs. What is the URL of the JSP view that produces these links? Have you tried using `/cities/${country.id}` for the links instead? What's the context root of your application? What's the servlet mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Several things look strange:

- you mixed city and country in the url
- Use 'c:url'!

Example:

```
   <c:url var="countryUrl" value="/country/${country.id}”/>
  <a href="${countryUrl}"> . . .
```